# call ajax function from other page from other page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i am working on chat application and here is my javascript code.

```
    function PushMessage(e , textarea) 
    {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if(code == 13) 
         { 
           //Enter keycode
           var text1 = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
           var div = document.getElementById('textmesage');
           div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<br>' + text1;
           document.getElementById('myTextArea').value = "";
            if (text1.length !== 0) {
                opner.sendMessage(text1);
                event.preventDefault();
         } else {
               alert('Provide a message to send!');
                                    }
           }
     }
```

from this upper code i want to call sendMessage(text1); ajax function from other page i also imbbed path for connection but it is not working, here is my ajax function

```
     sendMessage: function(message) 
          {
            alert('fakhir is jumping');
            var that = this;
            $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/add_msg.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: {msg: message},
            success: function(data)
            {
            $('#chatMsg').val('');
            that.getMessages();
            }
            });
          }
```

Comment: check your console for JS error

Comment: which code is the server side?

Comment: If you want to call other js file ,you should set as a global variable function

Comment: bomlist.php:231 Uncaught ReferenceError: opner is not defined
    at PushMessage (bomlist.php:231)
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.onkeypress (bomlist.php:1)                                           here is the error in console